# multiply each row by each row

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of 20k rows and 100 cols. I want to perform division operation between all possible pairs of rows. This would create <20k choose 2> combinations of vectors. How to do it most efficiently in R programming language?

Comment: can post a sample with a simple matrix (like 4 lines, 3 columns) and explain what you want to achieve by giving the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- 20
x <- matrix(rnorm(2 * n), nrow = n)
apply(
  combn(nrow(x), 2),
  2,
  function(y){
    x[y[1], ] / x[y[2], ]
  }
)
```